# Get caller of trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Can you advice me how I can retrieve caller ID or Name which executed a trigger?

For example I want to know which SP executes a trigger or maybe trigger called by updates from management studio?

I know that @@PROCID returns ID of trigger and can't be used.

Also I know solution when in SP we write CONTEXT_INFO and read it from trigger.
But in this case we should SET CONTEXT_INFO in all SPs that modifies some table.

Is there exists some simplest way like @@PROCID ?

Comment: Are you looking for the name of the calling object or the name of the calling user/security principal?

Comment: Not really. It is possible to get the TSQL call stack using extended events but this is a heavyweight thing not suitable for general use in a trigger.

Comment: @Quantum Elf: I looking for name of the calling object or it ID

Comment: @Martin: Yes, Looks like I will take technique with CONTEXT_INFO

Answer (score 5):

If it's SQL Server 2005 or 2008, and a DDL trigger, you can use `eventdata()`.

[Here's a link to the msdn page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173781.aspx)

Basically it returns an XML dataset that you can parse to get things like who called it (`data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]`), what the command was, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately eventdata() not suitable because my trigger is DML

Comment: @Anton - then as far as I am aware, you can't get what you are after.

Comment: Anyway thanks for reply, now I know about eventdata() for future